# Please explain what "Array.push({objectRef})" is actually doing in JS?

Tags: javascript

I realise this may be a silly one to most people, but since I don't even know what this is called, I've been unable to find any more information online..

To share an oversimplification of my code; without really thinking about what I was doing, I ended up with something much like the following:

```
var myArray = [];
var firstObject = {...};
var secondObject = {...};

myArray.push({firstObject, secondObject});
```

In Chrome, when I inspected the array contents, I had an array of objects exactly as I expected. If I `JSON.stringify(myArray)`, I get the following out:

```
[{"firstObject":{"ping":"pong"},"secondObject":{"ping":"pong"}}]
```

However, when someone else tried this in IE, it complained about the syntax and the `.push()` call failed.

I realised afterwards that what I actually *intended* to do was:

```
myArray.push({
  firstObject: firstObject,
  secondObject: secondObject
});
```

Fortunately the code that uses this array didn't need to change, but I'm still a tad confused by this.. Could somebody point me in the direction of what this is called? Is this something from the newer ES6 syntax?

Comment: @Ivar he's clearly confused about why it works in one browser but not another

Comment: Like @TKoL said, `push()` appends an element to the array stack, in your case you're appending an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myArray.push({firstObject, secondObject});
```

Is ES6 syntax and in fact desugars into:

```
myArray.push({
  firstObject: firstObject,
  secondObject: secondObject
});
```

So IE complained because it had no support of that new syntax.

You can read about it (and some more) [here](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) or in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Link to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Comment: Thank you.. Knowing what to search for makes a world of difference. :)